# Text displaying in one line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a form which uploads a file. After the file is uploaded, I have made a function to display the text inside the uploaded file.

However, when the text is presented, it displays in one line. How do I make it do it displays in multiple lines?

```js
function loadFileAsText() {
  var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];

  var fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
    var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
    document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value = textFromFileLoaded;
  };

  fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
}
```

```css
#inputTextToSave {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 8pt;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 10pt;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <tr>
    <td>Select a File to Load:</td>
    <td><input type="file" id="fileToLoad"></td>
    <td><br><br><button onclick="loadFileAsText()">Load Selected File</button>
      <td>
        <td>
          <div><input type="text" id="inputTextToSave"> </div>
  </tr>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input` element can only be used for single line data. Maybe you want to use the `textarea` element:

```
<textarea id="inputTextToSave" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Comment: Could you please mark this answer as the answer of your question. So that everyone can see that your question is answered!? Thanks :-)

Comment: Yeah, I can do that however, upvote is disabled for me.